# I want to do video streaming of IP TV from my app. How to do it? Can I do this using AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avplayer, iptv

I want to do video streaming of IP TV from my app. How to do it? Can I do this using AVPlayer? I have gone through some resources that use web URL of videos hosted on somewhere. 
I just want to be sure if its the same process when using an IPTV url. If not then what's the process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the process will be almost same and you can achieve this by using `AVPlayer`. iOS doesn't support RTMP or RSTP, so your stream would need to be a HTTP Live stream. From memory the codec choice is very limited too, eg if you supply H264+mp3 you won't get any sound despite iOS supporting mp3.

If you are starting then you must go through this GitHub project for liveIp stream. 
https://github.com/elpsk/ipTV

You may also need to look into live stream documentation of Apple,
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming?language=objc